# Entity Framework 4 - Stored procedure inordinately slow

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, stored-procedures

When executed from Management Studio the stored procedure finishes in <0.1s, but when executed via EF it takes over 2s.

Below is profiler output:

[image: Profiler output]

A bit ironic since the reason for creating the SP was to improve performance on an EF query that took around 1.2s.

**UPDATE**
For whatever it is worth, the SP result is mapped to an EF complex type. I call without any hocus pocus:

```
var menuTags = db.GetMenuTags(2, "en-US");
```

The SQL generated by EF is:

```
exec [dbo].[GetMenuTags] @CustTypeId=2,@LanguageId='en-US                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           '
```

The only difference is a bunch of blank spaces EF adds to the end of @LanguageId, but they don't affect the performance. I have tried the exact same SQL in MSSMS and it works just as well as without the blank spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SPs executed via EF always return all rows, could that be the delay.

Maybe posting your SP and the original EF generated SQL will help

**Edited to add what appears to be the solution**

Another thought (from days gone by) Parameter sniffing was oft the culprit for a slow SP which had been run by a developer with bad parameters and then set up a crappy execution plan. Adding the WITH RECOMPILE option to get a new plan based on decent parameters would resolve this problem mostly. Another cheat was to assign the passed in parameters into local sql variables (local to the SP) and only use local variables in the query.

Now you have the SP with a decent execution plan you should be able to remove the 'WITH RECOMPILE' and it'll still work. Parameter Sniffing problems are rare I would say.

Comment: "EF always return all rows". Not sure what you mean. It returns the rows i expect ie. same as when executed via MSSMS.

Will update the question.

Comment: What I mean is if you apply a Linq query to an entity that uses an SP then all records are returned from the SP BEFORE the Linq query is applied, whereas straight EF changes the SQL it sends to the DB dependant on the Linq. I wasn't sure if perhaps you were using Linq on the query to get only a few records, but executing the SP would bring back thousands. I hope that's clear - it doesn't look like it !

Comment: I might also add, perhaps you could try calling the SP directly with ADO.Net, completely cutting out EF and see if the performance changes.

Comment: Tried it and got same bad performance. What strikes me is that reads are always 1994243 when called from anywhere except MSSMS. From MSSMS it's always 4609.

Comment: At least that rules out EF as the culprit - no great help though in the grander scheme of things.

Comment: Another thought (from days gone by) Parameter sniffing was oft the culprit for a slow SP which had been run by a developer with bad parameters and then set up a crappy execution plan. Adding the WITH RECOMPILE option to get a new plan based on decent parameters would resolve this problem mostly. Another cheat was to assign the passed in parameters into local sql variables (local to the SP) and only use local variables in the query.

Comment: WITH RECOMPILE did the trick! I am dumbfounded! I couldn't get EF to do it the "Function import" way but i can use ExecuteStoreQuery and use the  Complex item class generated by EF as the return object.

var menuTags = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<MenuTags>("exec GetMenuTags 2, 'en-US' WITH RECOMPILE");

If you update the answer cred is due! Thanks man!

Comment: By the way, is using WITH RECOMPILE bad practice in any way?

Comment: Added WITH RECOMPILE to the SP itself. I can now use the EF created function at full speed! Life is beautiful!

Comment: It is but also an argument against stored procs - logic ends up in them and you never have to worry about this scenario with direct sql from EF. Just something to consider.

Comment: @Adam Tuliper You mean i should copy the SP's SQL and execute it from EF rather than having a stored procedure?

Comment: Sorry for the SPAM, but I thank you so incredibly much! I had a SP which took literally hours (!) to complete when called from within my code. Now it's finished in ~200 ms.

Comment: @fero No problem. Glad it helped someone else too